# How to add obstacles detected by LaserScan to the global costmap?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, costmap, global-costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add obstacles in the way of my robot. Even if they are detected by the laser scan, it's not until the obstacle comes in the local costmap's frame that the obstacle is noticed and added to the global costmap.

Please note that, I tried following and understanding the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps) and tried reading and understanding other similar questions on the forum... but I don't understand two things:

1. Setting up the costmap in the launch file: what is happening here? Is it necessary?
2. Loading the plugins in the yaml files... Why not just load them in the common yaml file since I am loading it under both namespaces (global and local) and what do they really mean?

I just stole these bits from ready made simulations and I cant seem to find anything that explains them properly, and I am pretty sure this is what is not allowing to add obstacles to my global costmap.

Here are my costmap param files:

`costmap_common_params.yaml`:

```
obstacle_range: 2.0
raytrace_range: 3.0
publish_frequency: 1.0
footprint: [[0.57, 0.75],[0.57, -0.75],[-1.153, -0.75],[-1.153, 0.75]]
# robot_radius: 0.18

plugins:
- {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
- {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

obstacles_layer:
  observation_sources: scan scan2
  scan: {sensor_frame: base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
  scan2: {sensor_frame: base_scan2, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan2, marking: true, clearing: true}

inflater_layer:
 inflation_radius: 1.0
```

`global_costmap_params.yaml`:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  static_map: true
  plugins:
  - {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  - {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
  - {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

`local_costmap_params.yaml`:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

`move_base.launch`

```
<launch>

  <master auto="start"/>
  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/jm/isaac/sdk/packages/eband_ros/maps/factory.yaml"/>

  <!-- Setting up costmap -->
  <node name="static_tf0" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="2 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_footprint 100"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <param name="base_global_planner" type="string" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" />

  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381118/how-to-add-obstacles-detected-by-laserscan-to-the-global-costmap?/) by [jmyazbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/74848/jmyazbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2021-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edited my `costmap_common_params.yaml` to look like this:

```
map_type: costmap
obstacle_range: 10.0
raytrace_range: 12.0
publish_frequency: 1.0
footprint: [[-1.045, 0.315],[-1.045,  -0.315],[0.39, -0.315],[0.39, 0.315]]
# robot_radius: 0.18

plugins:
- {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
- {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

obstacles_layer:
  observation_sources: scan scan2
  scan: {sensor_frame: base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, obstacle_range: 10.0, raytrace_range: 12.0}
  scan2: {sensor_frame: base_scan2, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan2, marking: true, clearing: true, obstacle_range: 10.0, raytrace_range: 12.0}

inflater_layer:
 inflation_radius: 1.0
```

Basically added, the `map_type`, and added more range to my `obstacle_range`. I also added the `obstcale_range` and `raytrace_range` for each `observation_sources` setup.

---

Originally posted by [jmyazbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/74848/jmyazbeck/) with karma: 22 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0